# Node Sequelize json field order

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

This node rest api to fetching and creating records, to creating while we getting last json field in first position.

```
router.post('/audit', async (req,res)=> {
const _audit=req.body;
 try {
    const __audit= await audit.create(_audit)
    res.status(201).json(__audit)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err)
  }
});
```

**JSON** *While creating why **updatedDate** coming first place*

```
{
    "updatedDate": "2020-03-01T11:35:27.984Z",
    "id": 11,
    "updatedBy": "Rod",
    "actions": "added",
    "oldData": "updated",
    "newData": "change",
    "entityType": "admin1",
    "entityId": "53"
}
```

```
router.get('/audit',(req,res)=>{

  audit.findAll()
    .then(a=>{
      res.json(a)
  }).catch(err=>{
    res.send('error'+err)
    res.status(400)
  })
});
```

**JSON** Here returns json is perfect while getting all data by findall(),While its also work fine with another http request.

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "updatedBy": "Rod",
        "actions": "added",
        "oldData": "updated",
        "newData": "change",
        "entityType": "admin1",
        "entityId": "53",
        "updatedDate": "2020-03-01T11:07:46.000Z"
    }
]
```

**Model** This is model to extract with sequelize with mysql

```
const Sequelize=require('sequelize')
const db= require('../database/db')


module.exports =  db.sequelize.define(
    'audit',
    {
        id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
        autoIncrement:true,
        primaryKey: true
        },
        updatedBy: {
        type:Sequelize.STRING(45),
        field: 'updated_by'
        },
        actions: {
        type:Sequelize.STRING(45),
        field:'actions'
        },
        oldData: {
        type:Sequelize.STRING(45),
        field:'old_data'
        },
        newData: {
        type:Sequelize.STRING(45),
        field:'new_data'
        },
        entityType: {
        type:Sequelize.STRING(45),
        field:'entity_type'
        },
        entityId: {
        type:Sequelize.STRING(45),
        field:'entity_id'
        },
        updatedDate: {
        type:Sequelize.DATE,
        field:'updated_date',
        defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
        }
    },
   {
    freezeTableName: true
   }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of fields in serialized/deserialized JS-object depends on browser/Node engine.
You should not rely on certain order of the fields because usually you access them by key.